# How does file creation work in Java

Tags: java, file, relative-path

I am trying to create a file using

> File newFile = new File("myFile");

However no file called "myFile" is created. This is within a Web application Project i.e. proper form to be pakaged as a WAR but I am calling it as part of a main method (just to see how this works).

How can I make it so that a new file is created at a location relative to the current one i.e not have to put in an absolute path.

**EDIT:**

> newFile.createFile();

Doesn't seem to work:

Here is the entire code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Tester test = new Tester();
    test.makeFile();
}

public void makeFile() throws IOException{
    File newFile = new File("myFile");
    newFile.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I expect the new file to be created - I would expect it to be in the same folder as the class it's being called from.

Comment: No, its in the current working directory. Use `file.getAbsolutePath()` to get the full path.

Comment: Note that File class represents a logical representation of a file and not a physical representation on disk.  You will need to use the createNewFile() method it has to actually do the physical creation, told in many answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your comment. The file will be created in the current directory of the process, unless you specifiy otherwise.

```
// new file in current directory
File f = new File("yourFile");
f.createNewFile();
System.out.println("Path:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
```

To create it in a directory of your choosing:

```
File f = new File("c:\\yourDirectory","yourFile");
f.createNewFile();
System.out.println("Path:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `newFile.createNewFile();`

Answer (score 2):

newFile.createNewFile();