# Why cant I see my xml file? When I run it, it executes with nothing there to show

Tags: java, xml

```
//The import files in use

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class WriteXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WriteXML t = new WriteXML();
        t.m();
    }

    private void m() {

        XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

        try {
        // Create the XMLStreamWriter object   
            // this is where it should create my file for xml

            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("products.xml");
            XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(fileWriter);

            //Here is the actual xml data        
            writer.writeStartDocument("1.0")   
            writer.writeComment("Product data");
            writer.writeStartElement("Products");

            writer.writeStartElement("Product");
            writer.writeAttribute("Code", "Java");

            writer.writeStartElement("Description");
            writer.writeCharacters("Java SE 6.0");
            writer.writeEndElement();
            // for the Product element

            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.writeStartElement("Product");
            writer.writeAttribute("Code", "C++");

            writer.writeStartElement("Description");
            writer.writeCharacters("C++ Programming");
            writer.writeEndElement();
            // for the Product element

            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } //catch statements
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A code dump, makes not a question.  `products.xml` will be written into the current working directory.  You can use `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` and print it to the console to determine from where the program is been executed...

Comment: how would you incorporate that into the current code?

Answer (score 0):

The file is probably being created in a directory that you don't expect, such as [the current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452738/how-does-file-creation-work-in-java). Try specifying an absolute path.

Windows example:

```
C:\Users\Walter\Desktop\products.xml
```